# Twilio how to wait correctly for outbound call answer?

Tags: twilio

I faced with the issue that Twilio call status changes to in-progress immediately after "ringing" for an outbound call. So it doesn't matter if you answer the call or not.
[here is log with timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9uOX.png)

here is a code:

```
var statusCallbackEvent = new List<string> { "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" };
            await CallResource.CreateAsync(new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber),
                                           new PhoneNumber(fromPhone),
                                           url:voiceResourceUrl,
                                           statusCallback:new Uri("url to events"),
                                           statusCallbackEvent: statusCallbackEvent,machineDetection: "Enable",machineDetectionTimeout: 60);
```

Also while using trial account when I wait a bit and answer the call, trial message already in progress.
Any suggestions?
p.s. Both numbers are twilio numbers

Comment: What type of number are you calling? Are you calling another Twilio number or another Communication Platform as a Service (CPaaS) number?

Comment: Both numbers are twilio numbers, but recipient number connected to RingCentral app and I'm using RingCentral to answer the calls

Comment: It is certainly possible Ring Central is answering the call immediately (which explains he immediate in-progress status) and then playing session progress tones as it connects you to the appropriate party. You can try calling you cell phone and see if the statusCallbacks work as expected.

Comment: Looks like issue related RingCentral it has virtual lobby and answer immediately. Are there any workaround how to detect that end user was connected or at least wait (maybe using Gather) and after that connect autopilot to the call?

Comment: You could wait for someone to enter DTMF (called `Human Detection`). So if someone presses a key, you know it is a human, https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I believe it will work for me. If machine is detected it will loop with Gather and ask to enter some key until retry count exceed. In case of human will start immediately.